# How can I replace typed characters by stars?

Tags: html, input

I want to make an input so that, when I type, the characters are replaced with stars like in the Facebook application.

```
<form action="{{ url('resetPassword/{token}') }}" method="post" >
         <input class="form-control hiden" type="email" name="email" placeholder="" value=" @if(Session::has('email'))
        {{ Session::get('email') }}
        @endif" /><br/>
         <label>Votre nouveau mot de passe *</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" id="pass" name="password" placeholder="" /><br/>
         <label>Confirmer votre nouveau mot de passe *</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" id="pass_reset" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="" /><br/>
         {{ Form::hidden('token', $token) }}
        <div class="btn_div">
          <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer mon nouveau mot de passe" class="btn btn-primary reset_btn" >
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```html
<input type="password" />
```

Comment: solved with  * dPassword v0.1 - jQuery delayed password masking (iPhone style)